# Using shapes in Semantic UI (CSS Framework)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-frameworks, semantic-ui

I have been struggling for some time on how to use shapes in Semantic UI.
I have been trying an example from their site http://semantic-ui.com/modules/shape.html#/definition but the animations are not working properly for me.

HTML CODE :

```
    <div class="ui cube shape">
        <div class="sides">
            <div class="active side">
                 <div class="content">
                    <div class="center">
                     1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="side">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="center">
                    2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('.shape').shape('flip up');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a JQuery version problem:

- [This fiddle works](http://goo.gl/HC9Vm6).
- [This one doesn't.](http://goo.gl/s0wy6G)

So check the JQuery version you're using, it seems that the version should be **upper than 1.8**.

Comment: thanks... JQuery version was ok...the problem was i guess linking two CSS framework (semantic and twitter Bootstrap)

Comment: @AnkurGoyal Maybe you should add to your question a Fiddle with your bug.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI and Bootstrap will not play nice together when it comes to Shapes. You will have to manually remove the following CSS in Bootstrap to make it work:

```
.hidden {
 display: none !important;
}
```

If having a .hidden class is crucial to your operation, rename it instead of removing it. Although I'm not familiar enough with Boostrap's inner workings to know if there are any internal dependencies on that class.